# JQuery closest() returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I am trying to get the value of a hidden input field using `closest()` but undefined is returned instead.

This is the html template:

```
<div class="content">
    <input type="hidden" value="ABC123" class="imgRef">

    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Item1" placeholder="description" value="{{item1}}" name="Item1" required>
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-fill addField">
                <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
            </button>
        </span>
      </div>
</div>
```

I try to read the value of the hidden input type with, which returns undefined:

```
    'click .addField':function(event){
        console.log($(event.currentTarget).closest('.imgRef').value);
    }
```

Comment: Can you create a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: That doesn;t work that way. `closest` goes up (or down I believe) in the DOM tree.. going up from where you clicked isn't going to get the input you want. You need to find its parent and than do a `.find('.imgRef')`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`.closest`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) traverses up in the DOM. `.imgRef` isn't any of the parents from the object you are clicking. You need to select the parent of that object (which IS one of the parents from that object you click) and than `.find('.imgRef')`.

Also, as @Daniel says in his answer, you need `.val()` instead of `.value`.

So :

```
console.log($(event.currentTarget).closest('.content').find('.imgRef').val());
```

See [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6nc56gdy/)

Comment: Thanks for the tips also.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you want in order to do this by a relative path from your button, without having to add IDs.

```js
     $('button').on('click', function(e) {
       var el = $(e.currentTarget).closest('.content').find('.imgRef').val();
       alert(el);
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <input type="hidden" value="ABC123" class="imgRef">

  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Item1" placeholder="description" value="" name="Item1" required>

    <button class="btn btn-default btn-fill addField">
      BUTTON
    </button>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oops. Looks like someone posted similar while I was writing this. lol